# Why is pandas join method throwing me an error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to join two dataframes (main_df and df).

```
print(main_df.head())
            NSA Value   SA Value
Date                            
1975-01-31  34.531020  34.725199
1975-02-28  34.996924  35.157220
1975-03-31  35.476331  35.517737
1975-04-30  35.990021  35.874357
1975-05-31  36.581159  36.283538

print(df.head())
            NSA Value   SA Value
Date                            
1975-01-31  35.759771  35.814004
1975-02-28  35.988479  36.049432
1975-03-31  36.246270  36.255031
1975-04-30  36.543662  36.493011
1975-05-31  36.784311  36.661750

main_df = main_df.join(df)
```

returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/PycharmProjects/untitled2/tester2.py", line 181, in <module>
    main_df = main_df.join(df)
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7209, in join
    other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix, rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7232, in _join_compat
    sort=sort,
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 88, in merge
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 649, in get_result
    ldata.items, lsuf, rdata.items, rsuf
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 2026, in _items_overlap_with_suffix
    "{rename}".format(rename=to_rename)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['NSA Value', 'SA Value'], dtype='object')
```

I still get an error when trying to join after explicitly specifying the index

```
main_df = main_df.set_index('Date').join(df.set_index('Date'))
```

Throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mbsta/PycharmProjects/untitled2/tester2.py", line 180, in <module>
    main_df = main_df.set_index('Date').join(df.set_index('Date'))
  File "C:\Users\mbsta\Anaconda3\envs\untitled2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4303, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"
```

I am trying to understand how join works and I cannot figure out why it wont join around the index (Date). Any clarity would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `join` joins along the `index`.  If you have 2 columns in both  dataframes, `join` should give you 4 columns.  However, your columns are named identically and that is what is causing the error.  You need to either rename the columns prior,  use the `lsuffix`/`rsuffix` arguments, or use `pd.concat({'main': main_df, 'other': df}, axis=1)` to get a MultiIndex

Comment: @piRSquared thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for clarify on. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to append df to main_df , then answer is:

```
pd.concat([main_df, df])
```

for left, right or inner joins,
you can use pd.merge function.

```
main_df.merge(df, on='date',how='left')
```

using merge function will not throw an error with same column names. But rather add suffixes itself.(like nsa_x, nsa_y)

Comment: Thank you!
This was helpful. 
Generally I do understand the other methods, but I wanted to figure out join and where it was breaking. I believe piRSquared comment in the original thread answers this!